# Cordova plugin not working with XCode 6.4

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, meteor, cordova-plugins

I have a meteor webapp and also a Cordova iOS app. I updgraded XCode from 6.3.2 to 6.4 and now I have an error whenever I try to build the Meteor Cordova app.

I get an error in NSData+Base64.m file. The NSData+Base64.m file is truncated in the build with the new XCode.

I downgraded back to XCode 6.3.2 and it works again. Does anyone else have this issue? If yes, were you able to figure out how to use Cordova with XCode 6.4?

Attached is the truncated: NSData+Base64.m file that is generated using XCode 6.4 for those who are interested.

[Truncated NSData+Base64.m file](https://www.evernote.com/l/AD9kNYVTY2RH8rJfvWKYdcQicwCnWXXyCwI)

Answer (score 0):

have you seen this?  i posted to the plugin and was able to get pass the issue:
  https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase/issues/251